# Better way to import library project in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I was wondering what is the recommended way of including library projects in an Android Studios gradle like this:

First way:

```
compile 'de.greenrobot:greendao:2.1.0'
```

Second way:

```
compile files('libs/greendao-2.0.0.jar')
```

and what are the pros and cons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First way: compile 'de.greenrobot:greendao:2.1.0'**

PRO:

- Easy, quick to update

CON:

- Internet connection required when updating your gradle file

**Second way: compile files('libs/greendao-2.0.0.jar')**

PRO:

- You can make changes to the library and those won't be overwritten.
- Like Qian Sijianhao said, it's quicker to build.

CON:

- More work to set up, update

In most cases I think you want to go with the first way.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case gradle is completely handling the process of dependency management, i.e. downloading the jar and including it in your project.

In the second case you have to manually download the jar and include it in the libs folder.

The simpler and preferred way is the first.

Comment: Oh great! But I wonder adding 1 line of dependency... not always adds any .jar.... still works.

Answer (score 1):

Trust me, the second way will save lots of your building time.
By the way , time is money.

Answer (score 1):

**In the first way**, i.e:

```
compile 'de.greenrobot:greendao:2.1.0'
compile 'com.library.sample:library:x.x.x'
```

Gradle will finding these dependencies, and making them available in your build. If your dependencies have a dependencies, gradle will also finding them and include it for the project. So you don't need to manually add all the dependencies.

Quoting from [Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html#sec:what_is_dependency_management):

> **7.1. What is dependency management?**
>
> Very roughly, dependency management is made up of two pieces. Firstly,
>   Gradle needs to know about the things that your project needs to build
>   or run, in order to find them. We call these incoming files the
>   dependencies of the project. Secondly, Gradle needs to build and
>   upload the things that your project produces. We call these outgoing
>   files the publications of the project. Let's look at these two pieces
>   in more detail:
>
> Most projects are not completely self-contained. They need files built
>   by other projects in order to be compiled or tested and so on. For
>   example, in order to use Hibernate in my project, I need to include
>   some Hibernate jars in the classpath when I compile my source. To run
>   my tests, I might also need to include some additional jars in the
>   test classpath, such as a particular JDBC driver or the Ehcache jars.
>
> These incoming files form the dependencies of the project. Gradle
>   allows you to tell it what the dependencies of your project are, so
>   that it can take care of finding these dependencies, and making them
>   available in your build. The dependencies might need to be downloaded
>   from a remote Maven or Ivy repository, or located in a local
>   directory, or may need to be built by another project in the same
>   multi-project build. We call this process dependency resolution.
>
> Note that this feature provides a major advantage over Ant. With Ant,
>   you only have the ability to specify absolute or relative paths to
>   specific jars to load. With Gradle, you simply declare the “names” of
>   your dependencies, and other layers determine where to get those
>   dependencies from. You can get similar behavior from Ant by adding
>   Apache Ivy, but Gradle does it better.
>
> Often, the dependencies of a project will themselves have
>   dependencies. For example, Hibernate core requires several other
>   libraries to be present on the classpath with it runs. So, when Gradle
>   runs the tests for your project, it also needs to find these
>   dependencies and make them available. We call these transitive
>   dependencies.

Gradle will store the downloaded library to your `USER_HOME/.gradle`. In Linux, it will store it in `/home/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/`. in Mac it will store it in `~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/`.

By the way, if you have used the library, you can set Android Studio to use a local cache of the library.

---

**In the second way**, you need to manually add the library for your project. And you also need to include all the remaining dependencies of the library. This is so error prone.